# Element to be only visible where it's overlapping specific other element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I'm trying to achieve the following:
I have an image in the background and a moving element in the foreground. I want to show the foreground element only while it's overlapping the background element. In the snippet below, the globe represents the background element, and the red square is the foreground element.
Here is a demonstration what I want it to look like:

[image: Example]

The first things that came to mind were the css clip-path and mask-image properties, but I couldn't really get it to work.

Thanks in advance!

```css
.world {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

.world img{
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

.testelement {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 75px;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="world">
  <img src="https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/bfd975773964bd26a28b9eecfb96b970/L0KzQYm3U8I6N5hwj5H0aYP2gLBuTgdwep1pRdl1b3LoPbTzigAuaaN5RddqcoTrPbTokwRwd58yTdNrZETkdom4VvU3QWczUKgBMEK2R4a4VcIzO2Y5UaUBMEm2SHB3jvc=/kisspng-world-globe-clip-art-earth-cartoon-5abd4af816e696.8660237515223549360938.png"/>
</div> 
<div class="testelement">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea with `mask`. Simply use the same image inside the mask on the container where the size is defined by the image. Then make the red square inside that container:

```css
.world {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width:300px;
  -webkit-mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/2qmJjxR/kisspng-world-globe-clip-art-earth-cartoon-5abd4af816e696-8660237515223549360938.png)
               center/contain no-repeat;  
          mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/2qmJjxR/kisspng-world-globe-clip-art-earth-cartoon-5abd4af816e696-8660237515223549360938.png)
               center/contain no-repeat;
}

.world img{
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
}

.testelement {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: 150px;
  transition:1s all;
}

.world:hover .testelement{
 left:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="world">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/2qmJjxR/kisspng-world-globe-clip-art-earth-cartoon-5abd4af816e696-8660237515223549360938.png">
<div class="testelement">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be aware that CSS mask is not fully implemented on all browsers yet : https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks

Comment: @Oddrigue All modern browsers support it at least partially to make this easy example working.

Comment: Thanks alot! I will try it out right away. In my specific use case it's for an electron app so browser support is not an issue.